# maximum value for timer

Tags: c#, timer

what is the maximum interval for a timer to work in C#?

is it the maximum value of int 32?

can i change it to int 64?

If i change, that is ONE big IF, will a timer still be working?

Comment: A what timer B Have you looked at the documentation.  Also What are you timing most of the timers are in milliseconds which gives you a timer of over a year.

Comment: just a normal timer.

I didn't find the maximum value for that.

Comment: @rerun - a millisecond timer with a max count of 0x7fffffff gives you a max timeout of about 24 days, not a year.

Comment: @Michael Burr dived by wrong term forgot 24 for hours in a day. 24.8 days still a long timer.  And better solved by an event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[System.Timers.Timer.Interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx):

> The time, in milliseconds, between
>   Elapsed events. The value must be
>   greater than zero, and less than or
>   equal to **Int32.MaxValue**. The default
>   is 100 milliseconds.

You cannot assign an Int64 to an Int32 (that is larger than  `Int32.MaxValue`)

Of interest: [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough if you search for winforms timer it [comes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval.aspx) right up.  The interval property is an int.