# 2100 hour + 1 minute as a timer.interval

Tags: c#, timer

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993765/maximum-value-for-timer) says "" The time, in milliseconds, between Elapsed events. The value must be greater than zero, and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue" [2,147,483,647]

However, I need 2100 hours plus 1 minute as a Timer.Interval. [7,560,000,000]

How to solve this, There's another way?

Comment: That's almost 90 days. Don't use timers for measuring time on that scale. Surely a scheduled task would be more robust.

Comment: A timer measures events in *milliseconds*, which are 1/1000 of a second. Don't try to use it to measure things that aren't reasonable to express in that scale. It's like using pennies (1/100 of a dollar) to pay your $2,000 mortgage.

Answer (score 4):

Timers shouldn't live anywhere near that long.  Fire a short timer periodically, and check the system clock to see if it's time to perform your long-running event or not.

Better yet, use [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), which is already designed for this.